# sfdx-lwc-jest' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am trying to run LWC Jest test, While i'm run this command:"sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:run"

I am getting this error: 'sfdx-lwc-jest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,'.

Error body is:

```
C:\Testing\Auto59\test>sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:run
'C:\Testing\Auto59\test\node_modules\@salesforce\sfdx-lwc-jest\bin\sfdx-lwc-jest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Test run complete. Exited with status code: 1
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test

Answer (score 3):

This feature isn't installed by default.

You can add it via:

```
sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:setup
```

Or:

```
npm install
npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev
```

*(The first `npm install` is not a typo; this is used to install all other named packages in `package.json` and their dependencies.)*

Once installed, the command should then work as documented.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_installation).

Comment: This is still not working,  I  am gettting the same error , package.json  already the has script block
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "test": "npm run test:unit",
        "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
        "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch",
        "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
        "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage"
    },